# SeekBar skipping values with no apparent reason

Tags: android, seekbar

So ,I have simple seekbar and when I move the thumb from the upper side to the down side, it skips values.

Any ideas how to fix this up?

Due to a confidentiality agreement,I cannot post more code than I posted here

If any other information but code is needed ,I'll try to answer asap.

```
SeekBar bar;

bar = new SeekBar(getActivity());

bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Log.i("Value:", ""+value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {

                value = arg1;


            }
        });
```

So, when I drag the thumb down from the top ,it simply skips values. (ONLY from the top!)

Comment: We are not magicians here, if you need debugging, we need to see code.

Comment: I have tried your code with bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1); and each value from 0 to 100 and from 100 to 0 are exactly printed.

Comment: Yea apparently the problem is not the seekbar but some other stuff that I do while using it.

Figured out what's the problem anyways...gonna post the answer in a sec for the others to know that there's no problem with the actual seekbar.

Answer (score 0):

So ,the problem was not the seekbar itself but some other stuff I was doing inside the onPorgressChanged method.

Again,due to a confidentiality agreement I cannot post ,but just clear a bit the confusion ,I was simply using the returned int from the seekbar to do calculations with it.